# Destructure arbitrary object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, object-destructuring

Is there a way I can destructure object into its arbitrary property value and the rest of the properties?

So far, my attempts didn't give much success:

```
const x = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
const obj2pieces = (obj,propName) => {
    ({propName,...rest} = obj);
    return [propName, {...rest}]
};
console.log(obj2pieces(x, 'a')); // [undefined,{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]
```

What I would like to get instead is `[1,{"b":2,"c":3}]`.

Comment: Use bracket notation, just like when assigning or looking up a variable in a property. `const {[propName]: val,...rest} = obj;` and `return [val, rest]` (no need to spread `rest`there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and a renaming for the extracting value.

```js
const
    x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
    obj2pieces = (obj, propName) => {
        const {[propName]: temp, ...rest } = obj;
        return [temp, rest]
    };

console.log(obj2pieces(x, 'a'));
```